# Extract specific columns from csv file in csv format itself

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csv

I require to extract specific column's data from CSV file and output should also be a CSV format.
I have gone through many solutions about extracting data from CSV but none of them talks about extracting it in CSV format itself

Example :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                string filePath = "abc.csv";

                string csvContnet = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

                // E.g. Suppose above csv has 9 columns
                // And column headers are from A,B,C...I
                // Now I want to select data from columheaders B,C and F along with header
                string requiredCsvContent = this.GetRequiredCsvContent(csvContnet);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Following function returns required CSV content from main csv File
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="csvContnet"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            private string GetRequiredCsvContent(string csvContnet)
            {

            }}
```

Comment: Could you post an example?

Comment: Please go through edits

Comment: Could you clarify the example? You have 9 headers (A -> I) but only 7 columns?

Comment: Removed unwanted headers from above example

Comment: @Nilesh what should be the format of the _output_ ?

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like a TSV (tab separated values) file. Just copy the whole thing into your clipboard and paste it into Excel. Then, delete all columns except D, E and F. Lastly, go to File > Save As > CSV.

Comment: lol this answer is so simple, ingenious, and funny all in one +1

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `File.ReadLines` or `File.ReadAllLines` so you can get what you want with `LINQ` easily:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("asd")
              .Skip(1) // header
              .Select(line =>
              {
                  var parts = line.Split(',');
                  return string.Join(",", parts[1], parts[2], parts[5]);
              }).ToList();
```

That should return `A`,`B` and `F` columns in *comma-seperated* format.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it correctly, you want to extract the headers and data from columns B, C, and F, and put the output into CSV format within a string? Try this out, using [IdComLog.Data](http://www.nuget.org/packages/idcomlog.data) (full disclosure, I am its author):

```
var data = from row in IdComLog.Data.Formats.Csv.ReadRecords("inputFile.csv")
           select new[]{ row[1].Value, row[2].Value, row[5].Value }

var sw = new StringWriter();
IdComLog.Data.Formats.Csv.Write(sw, data);

string requiredCsvContent = sw.ToString();
```

Highly recommend not using `Split()` or `Join()` to work with CSV. It will break on non-trivial data.